# Where do the funds go when we loose the stake in PoS (Casper Update)?

Tags: blockchain, proof-of-stake, decentralization

In PoS, we know that if the validator try to mess with the blockchain, they loose their funds...where that fund goes ??? tell me please

Answer (score 1):

That fund is burned completely. Becose by burning less Ether will be in existance, that means that the price of one Ether should go up. The deposit is effectively distributed to everyone that owns Ether propotional to the amount they have.